# recurrence relation and find sum

Tags: calculus

If you know that the coefficient $a(n)$
$$3 a(n+1)-n a(n)=0,a(0)=\frac{1}{2}$$
it possible to do a different root relation about the sum $S(n)$
so that $$S(n)=\sum _{k=0}^n a(k) B(n,k)$$
thanks

Comment: Who is this $B$?

Comment: @MarcoDisce Presumably the Bell numbers.

Comment: B(n,k) is any function hypergeometric or polynomial the question is about to get some type os recurrence formula for S(n) knowing the recucrrence of a(n) .

Answer (score 1):

$a(n+1)=\frac{n}{3} a(n)=\frac{n(n-1)}{3^{2}}a(n-1)=\ldots=\frac{n!}{3^{n}}a(1)$.

But $a(1)=\frac{0}{3} a(0)=0$, then $a(n)=0$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$??